# Using Google Hovercard API vs Jquery Hovercard

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know how to use the Google Hovercard API example?

I downloaded the zipped source code, tested it - and it does work.

Then I tried to replicate and simplified its original source code like so..

Google HoverCard
          </script> -->

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../base.js"></script>


        <script>
          goog.require('goog.debug.DivConsole');
          goog.require('goog.debug.LogManager');
          goog.require('goog.log');
          goog.require('goog.positioning.AnchoredPosition');
          goog.require('goog.positioning.Corner');
          goog.require('goog.ui.Component.EventType');
          goog.require('goog.ui.HoverCard');
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/hovercard.css">
      <style>
          #personEmail {
            font-style: italic;
          }
          .anchor {
            font: bold;
            color: white;
            background-color: gray;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
          }
      </style>

  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>HoverCard Test</h1>
      <span class="anchor" email="tom@gmail.com">Tom Smith1</span>
      <span class="anchor" email="tom@gmail.com">Tom Smith2</span>
      <span class="anchor" email="tom@gmail.com">Tom Smith3</span>

      <div id='profileCard' style="display:none;position:absolute">
  <div style="position:relative;left:2px;z-index:100">
   <table class="goog-hovercard-icons">
     <tr>
       <td>Email</td>
       <td>Chat</td>
       <td>More</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="goog-hovercard-content">
      <tr>
         <td valign="top">
              <span id='personName'>&nbsp;</span><br />
              <span id='personEmail'>&nbsp;</span>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
   <script>
    function writeDiv(top, left) {
      var width = 300 + 10;
      var height = 115 + 10;
      document.write(
          '<div class="goog-shadow" style="position:absolute;left:' +
          left + 'px;top:' + top + 'px;width:' +
          width + 'px;height:' + height + 'px;z-index:10" ></div>\n');
    }

    var y = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var size = 6;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      for (var j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        writeDiv(y + i, left + j);
      }
    }
  </script>
  </div>

  <script>
    var timer = goog.now();

    // Set up a logger.
    goog.debug.LogManager.getRoot().setLevel(goog.log.Level.ALL);
    var logger = goog.log.getLogger('demo');
    var logconsole = new goog.debug.DivConsole(goog.dom.getElement('log'));
    logconsole.setCapturing(true);

    var EVENTS = goog.object.getValues(goog.ui.HoverCard.EventType);
    goog.log.fine(logger, 'Listening for: ' + EVENTS.join(', ') + '.');

    function logEvent(e) {
      goog.log.info(logger, 'HoverCard dispatched: ' + e.type);
    }

    // Initialize hovercard object.
    var hc;
    hc = new goog.ui.HoverCard({SPAN: 'email'});
    hc.setElement(goog.dom.getElement('profileCard'));
    goog.events.listen(hc, goog.ui.HoverCard.EventType.TRIGGER,
                       onTrigger);
    goog.events.listen(hc, goog.ui.HoverCard.EventType.BEFORE_SHOW,
                       onBeforeShow);

    hc.className = 'goog-hovercard';

    var config = {
      'right': goog.positioning.Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
      'down': goog.positioning.Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT
    }

    function onTrigger(event) {
      // Usually, you will only need to respond to the TRIGGER event if
      // you want hovercard triggers to have different behaviors.
      var trigger = event.anchor;
      var conf = trigger.getAttribute("config");
      var pos = null;
      if (conf) {
        pos = new goog.positioning.AnchoredPosition(trigger, config[conf]);
      }
      hc.setPosition(pos);

      return true;
    }

    function onBeforeShow() {
      // This is where you typically set the contents of your hovercard,
      // based on the triggering element.
      var trigger = hc.getAnchorElement();
      var email = trigger.getAttribute("email");
      var name = trigger.innerHTML;
      var emailEl = goog.dom.getElement('personEmail');
      emailEl.innerHTML = email;
      var nameEl = goog.dom.getElement('personName');
      nameEl.innerHTML = name;

      return true;
    }

    goog.events.listen(hc, EVENTS, logEvent);

    goog.dom.setTextContent(goog.dom.getElement('perf'),
        (goog.now() - timer) + 'ms');

</script>


  </body>
```

It broke and it comes up with numerous exceptions like goog is not defined and the required. js are not loaded etc, etc.

I find this very cumbersome to write up a simple hovercard html file and I'm wondering does anyone have better luck in using Google hovercard in their projects much easier.  Or would I'd better off to use JQuery Hovercard to achieve the same results?

What are your thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this.

I didn't read the documentation and the demo API further to test the Google Hovercard examples.

Thus I finally managed to get it working in one of my projects.

Cheers!